# python delayed loop without new line waits until loop is finished to display text

Tags: python, loops

I have a loop in python that is sleeping 0.1 seconds every iteration. It is sequentially printing out a string to the console. I want it to add a character every iteration, But the problem is that it waits until the loop is finished to display the text. This only happens when I have the ", end='' " bit at the end of the print call.

```
import time

def speak(text):
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, len(text) + 1):
        print(text[i], end='')
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)

speak("Test 123. Can you see me?")
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Add the flush parameter to the `print` function to get it to print immediately: `print(text[i], end='', flush=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, you need `flush=True` in your call to `print(...)`.

Also, your loop goes one character off the end of the string (causing an exception), and it would be nice to print a newline at the end of the text. Here's a fixed up version that works on my machine:

```
import time

def speak(text):
    for c in text + '\n':
        print(c, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)

speak("Test 123. Can you see me?")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm kinda new to python. I love how fast this community responds to questions!